# Issue in using Powershell return in a statement

Tags: powershell

```
function a()
{
   return 10
}

$b = 10
write-Host "b = $b"

[int]$b += a
write-Host "b = $b"

[int]$b = a + 10
write-Host "b = $b"

Output for the above script is:

b = 10
b = 20
b = 10
```

I have programming background in C and recently started programming in PS. I tried to write simple program which uses return value from a function in a statement. I am confused about the results. Following statements works differently.

```
[int]$b += a
[int]$b = a + 10
```

Can someone please explain me the reason?

Regards

Jugari

Comment: Also you don't need return statements in powershell function a()
{ 10 } is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes strange for a C programmer.

`[int]$b = a + 10` means that you call a function with two parameters try `[int]$b = (a) + 10`

retry using this function

```
function a()
{
   write-host $args.count
   return 10
}
```

You have also to be very careful to the values returned by a function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the interpreter is trying to pass '+ 10' as parameters to your function; because there are no parameters specified in your function they are set as null.  Putting parentheses around your function call will prevent this and I suspect work as you intend.

```
[int]$b = (a) + 10
write-Host "b = $b"
```